# Replacing list comprehensions with pandas and numpy Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, slice

The function below uses slices to get the maximum value between 2 indexes at once. So it gets the maximum value between `0 and 10` and then `10 and 12` and such. The function is derived from the answer to this post [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931080/slicing-and-getting-the-max-value-with-numpy-python/65931168#65931168). Is there a way I could could replace the list comprehensions in the form of a pandas function like `pd.Series()`. Or if possible do it as a numpy function.

```
list_ = np.array([9887.89, 9902.99, 9902.99, 9910.23, 9920.79, 9911.34, 9920.01, 9927.51, 9932.3, 9932.33, 9928.87, 9929.22, 9929.22, 9935.24, 9935.24, 9935.26, 9935.26, 9935.68, 9935.68, 9940.5])
indexes = np.array([0,10,12,14])
chunks = np.split(list_, indexes[1:-1])
MAX=([c.max() for c in chunks])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it for performance reasons or do you need results in the form of a numpy array?

Comment: `df.iloc[0:10].max()` just replace 0/10 with what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend this:

```
MAX = np.maximum.reduceat(list_,indexes[:-1])
```

output:

```
array([9932.33, 9929.22, 9940.5 ])
```

Another way that will NOT increase your performance and is merely a replacement for list comprehension in your answer (in fact, might even be slightly slower):

```
max = np.vectorize(np.max)
MAX = max(chunks)
```

Comment: Is there a way I could get the indexes of `9932.33, 9929.22, 9940.5` as well. I tried to implement `argmax` to it howwver it didnt workout

Comment: @tonyselcuk Quite a different question but does this post answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/41835843/4975981?

Comment: @tonyselcuk Glad it resolved. Please feel free to accept the answer to close the question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about the delay just did it now.